# Using groupby() and value_counts() with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, count

I have a dataframe, an example is shown below:

```
Type    Color
A       Blue    
A       Orange 
A       Green   
A       Green   
A       Red    
A       Red     
A       Red     
B       Blue    
B       Orange  
B       Green   
B       Green   
B       Red     
B       Red     
B       Red     
C       Blue    
C       Orange  
C       Green   
C       Green   
C       Red     
C       Red     
C       Red     
D       Blue    
D       Orange  
D       Green   
D       Green   
D       Red     
D       Red     
D       Red     
E       Blue    
E       Orange  
E       Green   
E       Green   
E       Red     
E       Red     
E       Red
```

I want to make a new series named Count as shown below:

```
Type    Color   Count
A       Blue    1
A       Orange  1
A       Green   2
A       Green   2
A       Red     3
A       Red     3
A       Red     3
B       Blue    1
B       Orange  1
B       Green   2
B       Green   2
B       Red     3
B       Red     3
B       Red     3
C       Blue    1
C       Orange  1
C       Green   2
C       Green   2
C       Red     3
C       Red     3
C       Red     3
D       Blue    1
D       Orange  1
D       Green   2
D       Green   2
D       Red     3
D       Red     3
D       Red     3
E       Blue    1
E       Orange  1
E       Green   2
E       Green   2
E       Red     3
E       Red     3
E       Red     3
```

I want to print out the column 'Count' with the values that are listed.

Basically, I want to find the value_counts of each 'Color' within each 'Type'. For example, although the color Blue appears in the 'Color' column 5 times, the count is still 1 because it only appeared in Type A one time.

Another example would be the color Red. It appears in all of the types (A, B, C, D, and E) 3 times, so the count is listed as 3 for each red color.

I have tried using the following code but I do not see any new column created so I am not sure if this is working.

```
df.groupby(['Type', 'Color']).value_counts()
```

If I try to create a new column equal to the code above, then I receive a index error.

I want to print out a column called Count with the values shown above. How can I do this?

Comment: A new column with grouped data would (pretty much by definition) not have the same number of "rows" as the original data frame (ungrouped). You need to clarify what result you actually want to get - what would you expect to put in a "new column"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Type', 'Color'])['Color'].transform('count')
```

Documentation: [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html), [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.count.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, just need to convert it to a dataframe using `to_frame()`

```py
data = {'Type': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'A', 6: 'A', 7: 'B', 8: 'B', 9: 'B', 10: 'B', 11: 'B', 12: 'B', 13: 'B', 14: 'C', 15: 'C', 16: 'C', 17: 'C', 18: 'C', 19: 'C', 20: 'C', 21: 'D', 22: 'D', 23: 'D', 24: 'D', 25: 'D', 26: 'D', 27: 'D', 28: 'E', 29: 'E', 30: 'E', 31: 'E', 32: 'E', 33: 'E', 34: 'E'}, 'Color': {0: 'Blue', 1: 'Orange', 2: 'Green', 3: 'Green', 4: 'Red', 5: 'Red', 6: 'Red', 7: 'Blue', 8: 'Orange', 9: 'Green', 10: 'Green', 11: 'Red', 12: 'Red', 13: 'Red', 14: 'Blue', 15: 'Orange', 16: 'Green', 17: 'Green', 18: 'Red', 19: 'Red', 20: 'Red', 21: 'Blue', 22: 'Orange', 23: 'Green', 24: 'Green', 25: 'Red', 26: 'Red', 27: 'Red', 28: 'Blue', 29: 'Orange', 30: 'Green', 31: 'Green', 32: 'Red', 33: 'Red', 34: 'Red'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2 = df.groupby(['Type', 'Color']).value_counts().to_frame()
print(df2)

'''
             count
Type Color        
A    Blue        1
     Green       2
     Orange      1
     Red         3
B    Blue        1
     Green       2
     Orange      1
     Red         3
C    Blue        1
     Green       2
     Orange      1
     Red         3
D    Blue        1
     Green       2
     Orange      1
     Red         3
E    Blue        1
     Green       2
     Orange      1
     Red         3
'''
```

With this, the column index is `df2.columns`
And to see the row index use `df2.index`

Now you're ready to find the number of any Color in any Type.
For example if you're looking for number of Color 'Red' in Type 'A', use this:
`df2.loc[('A', 'Red'), 'count']` to get `3`